# Where should WordPress pre_cache_alloptions filters be registered?

Tags: php, wordpress

I have customized some wp-option return values with the dynamic [pre_option_{option}](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/pre_option_option/) hook and for completeness would like to also override these option values when they are returned via [wp_load_alloptions()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_load_alloptions/). This function has a hook that is available to allow for this customization: [pre_cache_alloptions](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/pre_cache_alloptions/).

However, although the hook exists there doesn't appear to be any way to call add_filter("pre_cache_alloptions", ...) early enough for it to take effect before the first call to wp_load_alloptions(). Since wp_load_alloptions() is called very early when loading WordPress, and since the values are cached on first-call, I haven't been able to register the hook in time for it to take effect. I have tried calling add_filter("pre_cache_alloptions", ...) during a mu-plugin load and also in a custom theme functions.php file, but neither of those places appear to hook in early enough for this to work.

The only solution I have found so far is to hack the actual wp-includes\plugin.php file and add in the add_filter("pre_cache_alloptions", ...) call right after the require of class-wp-hook.php at the top. This does work as expected when registered at that code point... but I'm searching for a way to register this filter so that it works without altering the core WordPress code.

Comment: Specifically, the issue is that wp_load_alloptions() is called from wp-settings.php (line 151) -> wp_not_installed() -> is_blog_installed() -> wp_load_alloptions(). This is with WordPress 5.2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since this hook must be registered after the [add_filter()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_filter/) function is declared in plugin.php, but before the first call to [wp_load_alloptions()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_load_alloptions/), the only user-customizable code point that appears to work is the optional custom db.php file, which is loaded in wp-settings via require_wp_db(). Adding a custom wp-content/db.php file with the necessary add_filter("pre_cache_alloptions", ...) reference at the top works as a means to register this customization in time for it to be useful. After much searching, this appears to be the only way to handle this without mucking with the core itself.